# SSRS 2008 R2 Querystring parameters Sharepoint Integrated Mode

Tags: reporting-services

I’m trying to run a report via the following url:

```
http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/_vti_bin/ReportServer?http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/reports/Test.rdl
```

However, I get a 401 Unauthorised error.

The reason I am accessing the report this way is so that I can pass some parameters (which I have taken off for now). I want to pass via queyrstring some mdx values which will be used to run the report.

The URL looks like this with the queyrstring parameters.

```
http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/_vti_bin/ReportServer?http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/reports/Test.rdl&rp:CostCentreCostCentreHierarchy=%5BCost%20Centre%5D.%5BCost%20Centre%20Hierarchy%5D.%26%5B1002%5D&TimeFiscalYearQuarter=%5BTime%5D.%5BFiscal%20Year-Quarter-Month%5D.%5BF%20Quarter%5D.%26%5B20123%5D
```

Basically the parameters are MDX values.

I'm sure this worked for me at one point - but not any more.

I’m hoping it’s a case of missing permissions somewhere?!

Could the issue be related to the _vti_bin folder. I used this as per the article: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx`

Opening the reports via Sharepoint from the respective lists, works fine - the reports run without any errors - its just when I use the _vti_bin url i get this issue. The querystring parameters do not work with the regaular report viewer url which is in the _layouts folder.

If there is a better way to do this then please advise also.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The following URL worked. The rp: command should prefix each parameter. Only the ampersand in the mdx value needs to be encoded.

```
http://Portal/dashboards/hr/reports/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/dashboards/hr/reports/Reports/Test.rdl&ParamMode=Collapsed&rp:CostCentreCostCentreHierarchy=[Cost Centre].[Cost Centre Hierarchy].%26[1002]&rp:TimeFiscalYearQuarter=[Time].[Fiscal Year-Quarter-Month].[F Year].%26[2012]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using only the RSReportViewer.aspx page located in the _layouts directory. Passing MDX Member Unique Names is fully supported. Use the Parameters Panel on RSReportViewer.aspx to add an MDX Member as a parameter and inspect the generated URL.

Comment: I did try that, unfortunately there is nothing in the url that relates to parameters

Comment: It doesn't update the URL? Annoying... try putting in the square brackets raw (unescaped) and only escaping the &s (with %26). So like `?rp:SomeParam=[Dimension].[Hierarchy].%26[Member]`

Comment: Yeah that doesnt work either.